# How to save username and password in an app so that we do not need to login the app?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, keychain

I am new to iOS i donot know how to save username and password in an app So that there is no need to fill login details in the app till then user do not logout the app. I save my username and password in NSUSerdefaults. I search on google. I found this could be done with KeyChainWrapper class . i tried that way but that will not give me useful result. AnyOne can me help out for this problem.He/She could be greatly appreciate for that.

Comment: Use the keychain, so that you are not holding passwords in the open. The keychain wrapper linked by @Larcerax seems a good one as it is simple and also seems to support the concept that you might want multiple usernames and passwords for a given service and to be able to query password by username. Most wrappers I have looked at tend to assume one user per service which is not ideal.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use the class NSUserDefaults

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"username" forKey:@"usersave"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"usernamexxx" forKey:@"passsave"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Get them using:

```
NSString *password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"passsave"];
NSString *username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"usersave"];
```

Comment: @Anbu karthik i want to do as we do in our facebook account.. till den we login the account whenever we did not click on logout button –

Comment: 1) you must store your username and password.
2) In your class you need to create the login method method "viewWillAppear"
3) Recover username and password.
4) Submit the request in your home.

Comment: NSUserDefaults permanently store your data in the memory of your ios.
Otherwise you can use a database Sqilite.

Comment: I already stored data in ns user default. but when the time i run my app . the first screen opens up z login screen which i dont want

Comment: ok then in your class AppDelegate in the method  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool { retrieve the stored data. If the username and password exist then forwards the call to the class home

Comment: ok. If I was in your help I would be very grateful to have your vote click the plus symbol in my post. Thank you.

Comment: You should definitely not EVER store login information as an NSUserDefault. EVER.

Answer (score 5):

Use the iOS keychain. **Do Not** use user defaults to store potentially important information such as logins and passwords.

Here's some [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html) from Apple about its OS Keychain.

There's also this very handy, open sourced, wrapper around iOS Keychain called [UICKeychainStore](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore).

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if([[defaults objectForKey:@"remember"]isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
         ////for getting those values:


        _txt_email.text = [defaults objectForKey:@"username"];
        _txt_password.text = [defaults objectForKey:@"password"];

            // Login code
    }

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (IBAction)Login:(id)sender
{
   //To store valuses:


    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if([[defaults objectForKey:@"remember"]isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        [defaults setObject:_txt_email.text forKey:@"username"];
        [defaults setObject:_txt_password.text forKey:@"password"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }

    //Login here

}
```

Comment: i want to do as we do in our facebook account.. till den we login the account whenever we did not click on logout button

Answer (score 1):

easiest way is this, download this repo, and import it into your project:

https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain

Then do this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:USERS_USERNAME  forKey:@"com.yourapp.whateveryouwant"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

[SSKeychain setPassword:USERS_PASSWORD forService:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] account:USERS_USERNAME];
```

Using the SSKeyChain repo, you can sync your User's user name to the password and store it securely

You can retrieve it and check it by doing this:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"com.yourapp.whateveryouwant"]) {

    if ([SSKeychain passwordForService:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]
                               account:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"com.yourapp.whateveryouwant"]]) {

//do work

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**To store values:**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:@"username"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:@"password"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**for getting those values:**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey: @"username"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey: @"password"];
```

> NSUserDefaults will remove when your app will be removed from device. Otherwise it will store the values.

Comment: i want to do as we do in our facebook account.. till den we login the account whenever we did not click on logout button

Answer (score 0):

try this:

call below method after successful log in and when user uses app next time push directly to the next view.

```
+(void)setFirstLogIn:(BOOL)flag
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:flag forKey:@"FirstTime"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. If you are having more data to store after login, I would prefer to use CoreData or Sqlite. You can store create entity or table, and store you required data into that. Nexttime whenever you start app, Check it the values are stored or not.

Here the links which help you to start with basics for coredata and sqllite

CoreData Referral
http://www.raywenderlich.com/85578/first-core-data-app-using-swift

Sqlite Referral
http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/use-sqlite-database-swift